# Redmine REST API - users

Tags: api, rest, authentication, redmine

I am writing an application using data from Redmine. I use its REST API to get data.

It works fine with projects or issues, but when I try to access users' data I just can't because it asks for credentials in the browser, and it responds with HTTP error code 401 to my HTTP request from my program.

How do I find a solution to this problem?

```
Environment:
  Redmine version                          2.1.2.stable
  Ruby version                             1.8.7 (i386-mingw32)
  Ruby on Rails version                    3.2.8
  Environment                              production
  Database adapter                         MySQL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured out. It is described very detailed on the Redmine wiki.

There are a couple of options to authenticate yourself.

The easiest is to include a plus field in your query, named key. You must include your user's REST API key there in each query.

Like:

```
localhost/redmine/users.xml?key=eaksdnynkdnasdfnaskdsar
```

It is very interesting because in earlier versions (2.1.0) it asks for the authentication for each XML file. But in my version, 2.1.3, it doesn't ask, only if I request users data.

Comment: You can also use the HTTP Basic authentication. You just have to enable it in the Redmine Web interface settings.

Comment: You can also send your API key over in the HTTP header "X-Redmine-API-Key."